# How does Mixpanel's Search Keyword work?

Tags: analytics, keywords, search

[image]

I'm curious on how Mixpanel tracks which Search Keywords an event is affiliated with. Is this from the organic search (vs. paid search ads)?

If yes, how did they do it? From a glance, I guess organic search works this way:

1. [image]
2. That link goes to a proxy link with some query parameters which contain info about the (encrypted) search term & the real destination link.
3. Redirect to the real destination link.

Google Analytics knows the organic search keyword used on a session because they intercept it in the middle point. I'm [not sure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15781125/594601) if there's any way for someone outside of Google to intercept that info (including Mixpanel). Right? (correct me if I'm wrong)

If there is a way for the destination website to know the organic search keyword, can I be enlightened on the method?